# Iterating over a backbone collection

Tags: java, backbone.js

I would like to implement a pagination on my page according to the collection.
Each page should hold 20 items, thus page 1 will need to iterate over the first twenty models, the second page second twenty items, etc...

After reading some questions here, I have found that it can be done in the next way:

```
_.each(this.collection.slice(startIndex,startIndex+itemsPerPage),function(item) {
        console.log(item.get("name"));
    });
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use a plugin such as https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator which provides for pagination on client side (which is what you seem to want to do), as well as server-side pagination.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [this one](http://techiella.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/paginate-a-backbone-js-collection/) and it works pretty good:

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.partialEach = function partialEach(offset, maxItemsPerPage, iterator, context) {
    for (var l = this.length; maxItemsPerPage !== 0 && offset < l; offset++) {
        var model = this.at(offset);
        if(model) {
            iterator.call(context, model, offset, this);
            maxItemsPerPage--;
        }
    }
};
```